# Run out of components in Alien Isolation

Tags: xbox-360, alien-isolation

I'm currently on mission 13 (Consultation) of Alien Isolation on Xbox 360. I'm running into a lot of Industrial Synthetics (new at this point). And by running into I mean having their hands around my neck; which lowers health to the point of game over. I've only got a couple of molotovs and pipe bombs in my inventory and that's really not enough. I need more - only I don't have the resources to create them.

- I feel that I haven't been creating these items (weapons) as I go because I haven't needed them. Up until this point I've been hiding and sneaking around from all and sundry rather successfully.

However, since I lack enough fire-power to continue and evasion is almost impossible:

- Is my only course of action to go back several chapters and start building weapons as I go?  So by the time I get back to chapter 13 I'll have all the flaming booze I need to swamp those industrial synths.

All advice welcome thank you.

Comment: Also known as Locker Simulator 2014

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you are talking about the more expensive items to create so perhaps creating emps etc will be more efficient for you. I personally only ever used molotov's on the alien. Pipebombs were a panic device and I stunned synthetics (emp or stun baton) and  hit them with the wrench.

As soon as I got the pistol that was another way I dispatched them.

As you say it sounds like the key to your problem revolves around missing a lot of components and therefore not having enough to build with. From around chapter 10 onwards I had every gadget maxed out inventory wise most of the time.

I would track back as far as you can and look for components a bit harder. Most are in plain side but other can be well hidden. You might also find ammo for the stun gun which will be a jackpot in this case. If that fails go back a level or two and stock up on your way back to where you are now.

This is from my experience of completing the game on maximum difficulty. (PC)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you should pick up everything you find, even though you might not need it - sometimes you come in situations where fighting is unavoidable. But, to be honest, a few pipe bombs and molotovs are enough for these synths, you still got your weapon to punch the hell out of them. If you are lucky, you can get a EMP which makes fights against synths even easier.

Tracing the entire way back and build the weapons is your last option if everything else fails.